# Susy 2 not processing @include layout

Tags: css, ruby

I am using a Mac with Maverick. I am using Coda as my text editor.
I am using rvm which reports that I am using ruby 2.12, compass 1.0 rc1, sass 3.3.14 and susy 2.

I can add spans and other susy settings to my .scss file successfully but as soon as I try to use the @include layout(4 1/4 inside) rule in my .scss file 
I do NOT GET AN ERROR in my compass watch window **BUT my .css file does not reflect the rule and Chrome does not reflect that this rule has been added.**

I am not sure how to proceed because I am very unfamiliar with Ruby.

This is the output from gem list

addressable (2.3.6)
bigdecimal (1.2.4)
breakpoint (2.4.6, 2.4.2, 2.0.7)
bundler (1.6.5, 1.6.3, 1.6.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
celluloid (0.15.2)
chunky_png (1.3.1)
coderay (1.1.0)
color-schemer (0.2.8)
compass (1.0.0.rc.1, 1.0.0.alpha.21, 1.0.0.alpha.19)
compass-blend-modes (0.0.2)
compass-core (1.0.0.rc.1, 1.0.0.alpha.21, 1.0.0.alpha.19)
compass-import-once (1.0.5, 1.0.4)
compass-normalize (1.5)
compass-rgbapng (0.2.1)
compass-susy-plugin (0.9)
compass-validator (3.0.1)
css_parser (1.3.5)
em-websocket (0.5.1)
eventmachine (1.0.3)
executable-hooks (1.3.1)
ffi (1.9.3)
formatador (0.2.5)
fssm (0.2.10)
gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
guard (2.6.1, 1.8.2)
guard-compass (1.1.0, 0.0.8)
guard-livereload (2.3.0, 2.2.0, 1.4.0)
guard-shell (0.6.1)
http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
listen (2.7.9, 2.7.7, 1.1.6)
lumberjack (1.0.9, 1.0.6)
method_source (0.8.2)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.10.1)
oily_png (1.1.1)
pry (0.10.0, 0.9.12.6)
psych (2.0.5)
rake (10.3.2, 10.1.0)
rb-fchange (0.0.6)
rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
rb-inotify (0.9.5)
rb-kqueue (0.2.3)
rdoc (4.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.3)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sass (3.3.14, 3.3.10, 3.3.8)
sass-globbing (1.1.1)
sassy-maps (0.4.0)
sassy-strings (1.0.0)
singularitygs (1.1.2)
slop (3.6.0, 3.5.0)
susy (2.1.3, 2.1.2)
test-unit (2.1.2.0)
thor (0.19.1)
timers (1.1.0)
toolkit (2.5.2, 2.5.0, 2.3.0)
yajl-ruby (1.2.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `layout` mixin has no css output. All it does is change your global Susy layout settings. You probably want a `container` or `span` mixin to get started.